# How to connect Flutter app to tcp socket server?

Tags: sockets, dart, flutter, tcpclient

I had great difficulties to connect Flutter app to my network tcp socket on server. I know I have to use some sort intermediate option so translate data between tcp socket to flutter and Flutter to tcp socket.

Any idea, info how do achieve this. And question is How to connect Flutter app to tcp socket server?

Comment: Did you see this plugin? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_socket_io

Comment: does this plugin support HTTPS, SSL, TLC ... I couldn't see anything in their example, and their documentation doesn't saying anything about security

Comment: Dunno, actually never used it, just so you know in case you missed it. It is not clear from your question what you've already tried to do and what plugins you have tested.

Comment: If you just want a TCP socket use: `Socket s = await Socket.connect(host, port);` for SSL/TLS replace with `SecureSocket`. For HTTPS use `HttpClient` or `package:http`.

Comment: do you have any example for SecureSocket, I am using this operation inside aqueduct controller. My problem is the tcp socket always open. its old system and can get enough info how the socket build. rest I will post under your below answer

Answer (score 23):

Here's pretty much the simplest Dart program to connect to a TCP socket on a server. It sends 'hello', waits 5 seconds for any reply, then closes the socket. You could use this with your own server, or a simple echo server like [this one](https://github.com/venilnoronha/tcp-echo-server).

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  Socket socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.1.99', 1024);
  print('connected');

  // listen to the received data event stream
  socket.listen((List<int> event) {
    print(utf8.decode(event));
  });

  // send hello
  socket.add(utf8.encode('hello'));

  // wait 5 seconds
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

  // .. and close the socket
  socket.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, I did similar to this. I can connect to server and get data less than a second and I can see most data that I am getting around 55ms to 375ms. So waiting 5 second its huge slowness on Flutter mobile app.

Comment: I have 7 or 8 query that has a huge data. You use socket.listen. In my example I use for var data in socket loop. All of my query the loop runs once. but those 7 or 8 query I can see loops run 5 or 6 time. I don't know what is the end character of the data that I am getting from server. when I send query to server last bit I use \r\n

Comment: after \r\n server starts to send data back to me. It works very well in main() async {...} but I am having trouble in aqueduct Future<RequestOrResponse> handle(Request request) async {...}

Comment: I am using aqueduct as intermediate part of the communication between Flutter mobile app and the tcp socket on server. Do you thing if I switch to Server-Side Dart? Mobile app encrypt the data and send to server using https. the server front I have an nginx that sends the data back to 127.0.0.1:8888 (which is aqueduct). In aqueduct decrypt the data and change the data format and send to the server then aqueduct listens server and when gets the data does the formatting and encryptions and sends back to flutter mobile. if I switch to Server-Side Dart, maybe I can overcome my problem. Any info?

Comment: I'm just waiting 5 seconds before closing the socket by way of illustration. It doesn't introduce any 'slowness'! Why don't you know the end character from the server? Ask the designer or read the spec. The whole thing sounds very complicated. You need to explain your design, your implementation and then your issue. Your recent set of questions don't get high quality answers because nothing is clear in them. (The problem is, I think, that your design isn't clear. Unfortunately, SO is not a good forum for design questions as they tend to run foul of the "opinion" rule.)