# How to use ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteBuffer

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code in Java, how can I write it with dart?

I need to write some String to a Socket, but before it, I need to write the length of this string. So I use the ByteBuffer class to create some byte array with the string length, and after that I concatenate this two byte arrays. Thank you.

```
public void writeUTF(String s, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    if (s != null) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int length =  s.getBytes("UTF-8").length;

        // Create buffer
        byte[] bytesMessageLenght = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(length).array();
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();

        bytArray.write(bytesMessageLenght);
        bytArray.write(bytes);

        // Write
        out.write(bytArray.toByteArray());
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Dart `ByteData` which allows you to set the length directly, and then use `asUint8List` to make a byte array to copy in the rest.

```
Uint8List encode(String s) {
  var encodedString = utf8.encode(s);
  var encodedLength = encodedString.length;
  var data = ByteData(encodedLength + 4);
  data.setUint32(0, encodedLength, Endian.big);
  var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  bytes.setRange(4, encodedLength + 4, encodedString);
  return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Richard. I saved both byte arrays to a file (java version and dart version) and it seems that they are identical. But unfortunately, I can't get the answer from the socket server after connect and write with the Dart Version. I know that know it's other question, but could you help? This simple Main file in Java, can connect, write and listen to the socket. http://dontpad.com/tmp/socketjava. I tried to accomplish the same using dart but I was unable to read the response from the server http://dontpad.com/tmp/socketdart thank you.

Comment: Please ask as a new question.

Comment: Also, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481818/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-tcp-socket-server/54486106#54486106 Often a good idea to prefer `await` over `then` for readability.

Comment: Richard, thank you. I copied and paste your code from the other post, I changed the IP to my socket and it worked. Really thank you.